# should I link to Debug or Release dll with same name?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, linker

I was working on a MS Visual Studio project and noticed that the Debug build was Linking to a Release library (DLL), when a Debug library with the same name was also available. I switched the path to Link the Debug library, and it *seems* to still work. Is there any way to know if my change was correct?

Additional Information:

Using the debug DLL triggers a small memory leak that wasn't triggered with the release DLL. Or possibly that is debug related cache data. That leak made me question if it was including the lib headers without _DEBUG somehow. Thus this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the preferred way to link Debug builds of your program with Debug version of external dynamic libraries as it guarantees that uniform Visual C++ runtime libraries will be used. Mixing libraries built in Debug and Release mode will result in both Debug and Release VC++ runtimes being linked and annoying linker warnings about multiple symbol definitions in conflicting Debug/Runtime libraries.

Sometimes it may be inevitable as i.e. only Release version of some external library may be available. Hence in VC++ there are linker settings allowing to ignore some specific libraries. So you may start checking in the Linker-Input settings of the Debug build if such ignores are already defined for existing conflicts. With some luck you might be able to remove them now.

If using the Debug version of some library breaks the whole program it might be an insight how to improve the whole system, it is that what a Debug build is for anyway.

Comment: you said "If using the Debug version of some library breaks the whole program it might be an insight how to improve..." which reminds me that using the debug DLL triggers a small memory leak that wasn't triggered with the release DLL. Or possibly that is debug related cache data. That leak made me question if it was including the lib headers without _DEBUG somehow. Thus this question.

Comment: @Patrick Parker Probably you should track that leak further, application is not expected to have different behavior for Debug and Release compiler switches. Probably you should get sure that the Debug build is in sync with the Release version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is the right library (as in the same code compiled to a different configuration), you are right to link to the debug dll on your debug configuration (and should link to the release dll on your release configuration).

The differences tend to be related to the optimisation level (Debug is usually compiled without any optimisation at all) and any symbols that might be included to make it easier to develop with and maybe step into.

Comment: but what if someone has undef'd the _DEBUG prior to the #include, then re-defined _DEBUG? so I cannot be 100% sure

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you worried about the debug dll messing with code external to the dll?

Comment: That shouldn't be a concern here - the person doing the defining or not is you in this instance, so you have control over that.